# How to use rendezvous in its singular and plural forms?

Tags: word-usage, sentence, orthography, french

While I was reading a book I encountered the use of the word *rendezvous*, this is originally a French word according to the dictionary. The usage in the book was plural followed by “are”. Let me constructs some sentences and see whether my usage of its majesty *rendezvous* is correct:

Used as a noun; spelled `rahn-duh-voo`

> I had a **rendezvous** with a friend.

Like saying:

> I had a meeting with a friend.

Used as a simple past tense verb; spelled `rahn-duh-voo-ed`

> I **rendezvoused** with a friend.

Like saying:

> I met a friend.

As an answer to an interrogative sentence; spelled `rahn-duh-voo-ing`

> What are you doing?
>   I'm **rendezvousing** a friend right now.

Like saying:

> I'm meeting a friend right now.

Is my usage for the word *rendezvous* in the above sentences right?

Is the plural form of *rendezvous*, *rendezvous*?

Comment: You can get pronunciations in standard International Phonetic Alphabet notation from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rendezvous). The only difference between all those listed there is whether the first vowel is rounded and how much the middle syllable’s diphthong is reduced.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Rendezvous* is an appointment, i.e. the arrangement to meet rather than the act of meeting itself. So you wouldn't usually say something like “I'm rendezvousing with a friend right now”, because the immediacy of “right now” (your friend is supposed to be here) contradicts the potentiality of “rendezvous” (you don't know whether your friend has arrived). If you want to say that you have an appointment with a friend, it would be more idiomatic to say “I have a rendezvous with a friend right now” (you have an appointment, but you don't know whether your friend has arrived yet).

*Rendezvous* is not a very common word: “I'm meeting with a friend right now” would be the most common way to phrase this. The word *rendezvous* is a little highbrow and old-fashioned, and it's far more often a noun than a verb.

“I had a rendezvous with a friend” (you two had agreed to meet in a particular place at a particular time, or at least in a particular place during a particular time interval) is fine. So is “I rendezvoused with my friend” (we met at the time and place that we'd agreed). *Rendezvous* tends to focus on the meeting place; it can also be used to refer to a meeting spot even if there is no particular agreement to meet, e.g. “this café is a popular rendezvous for artists”.

*Rendezvous* is also used in the sense of a meeting actually taking place in other contexts that are about objects or abstract groups of people meeting. In this sense, it isn't particularly old-fashioned, and the verb doesn't sound more awkward than the noun. For example “the two armies rendezvoused on the plain” (they came to the same place and joined forces as arranged) or “the submarine will rendezvous with the battleship tomorrow” (they'll navigate to the same place and exchange personnel or supplies as arranged).

*Rendezvous* comes from the French word *rendez-vous*, and has kept almost the same spelling (only losing its hyphen) and a somewhat similar pronunciation (I think *ran-dey-voo* is more common than *ran-duh-voo*). The usual plural is identical to the singular, like in French. *Rendezvouses* also exists, but it's uncommon.

Comment: Indeed, I've never heard a reduced vowel in the second syllable myself.